# How can I compare out.writeObject("") with string?

Tags: java, android, regex, servlets

In my Android Login activity when user enters email and password the request goes to servlet and then servlet checks it in database. If email and password matches then it sends response back like below.

```
out.writeObject("matches");
```

Here out is

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

Now from my Android login activity I want to open another activity if email and password matches.Here is code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println(result);
        if(result.equals("matches"))
        {
            System.out.println("valid user");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Photos.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

But I can not enter in if condition.I print the value of String result that shows matches,and my toast message is also display matches when email and password match.But even though `result.equals("matches")` does not satisfied.And I am not getting any error also. I know I am making mistake somewhere but I don't know where. I also try

```
if(result.toString().equals("matches"))
```

But can't get output.

Comment: Maybe you have some non-printable characters.

Comment: but System.out.println(result) prints matches in just above line of if condition

Comment: The definition of non-printable implies that you won't see it in the `println()`

Comment: .toString() won't do anything, since result is already a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try trimming the string:

```
if(result.trim().equals("matches"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot now I am able to open new activity

Comment: Perfect, please upvote and accept if your found the answer useful.

Comment: i am trying to accept the answer I cant I can do it after 6 minutes

Comment: @bhargavthanki If that fixed it, you didn't have this code at all: `out.writeObject("matches");`. You had `" matches"` or `"matches "` etc.